# Python convert time duration in words to seconds

Tags: python

I am using external program which outputs time in this format.

```
15mn
1h 15mn 3sc
34 sc
```

How can I convert all such strings in words to seconds  i.e (15mn = 900 seconds)?

Comment: What exactly are you asking for? Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: You could split the output to take an array of ['1h','15mn','3sc']. Then foreach ellemetn of the array you could read the characters that are not digits and the the digits of the element. So if you read h and 1 you should write 1*3600s and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another one:

If you just specify a function which extracts out numbers with specific tags after them ...

```
def fs(x, p):
     p = re.sub('\s+', '', p) # get rid of spaces ...
     if re.search('[0-9]+'+x, p): # exp = (n digits) + (tag 'x') 
         return int( re.search('[0-9]+'+x, p).group()[:-len(x)] )
     else: return 0
```

Then you can subsequently just use the numbers for your computations ...

```
def toSec(p): return fs('h',p)*3600 + fs('mn',p)*60 + fs('sc',p)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an `re` a `dict` to get a multiplier, eg:

```
import re

text = '1h 15mn 3sc'
in_seconds = {'h': 60 * 60, 'mn': 60, 'sc': 1}
seconds = sum(int(num) * in_seconds[weight] for num, weight in re.findall(r'(\d+)\s?(mn|sc|h)', text))
# 4503
```

It's important to note that this allows constructs such as "1h 3mn 5h 3sc 12mn 2h 5sc" so may not be desirable...

Answer (score 0):

I use a (rather complex :)) regex to parse your string.

```
>>> def s_to_secs(s):
        import re
        mat = re.match(r"((?P<hours>\d+)\s?h)?\s?((?P<minutes>\d+)\s?mn)?\s?((?P<seconds>\d+)\s?sc)?", s)
        secs = 0
        secs += int(mat.group("hours"))*3600 if mat.group("hours") else 0
        secs += int(mat.group("minutes"))*60 if mat.group("minutes") else 0
        secs += int(mat.group("seconds")) if mat.group("seconds") else 0
        return secs
>>> for s in ("15mn", "1h 15mn 3sc", "34 sc"):
        print(s_to_secs(s))
900
4503
34
```

Answer (score 0):

Came across this looking for something else.  Here's a much cleaner simpler solution using [Python Pints](https://pint.readthedocs.io/)

```
import pint
ureg = pint.UnitRegistry()

ureg.define("mn = minutes") # Define non-standard units
ureg.define("sc = seconds")
ureg.define("h = hours")

def parse_odd_time_format(s):
    duration = ureg("0 seconds") # Just something to initialize
    for x in s.split(" "):
        duration += ureg(x) # Parse all the bits and add them together 
    return duration.magnitude # Split off the seconds

parse_odd_time_format("1h 15mn 3sc")
```

Comment: There are other answers that provide the OP's question, and they were posted some time ago (> 5 years). When posting an answer [see: How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), please make sure you add either a new solution, or a substantially better explanation, especially when answering older questions. If necessary, you should also add version information.